# SVN hooks stopped working suddenly

Tags: apache, svn, apache2, hook, svn-hooks

Our hooks have stopped working suddenly. All was working fine and suddenly stopped - no updates have been done to env. whatsoever.

To add to this, hook is working when executed as a apache user in shell but not when committing through apache http.

All prvilages are fine and as I wrote above all was working fine before with same settings... any ideas?

subversion ver: 1.6.6
apache ver: 2.2.3

i.e. this is a hook which we testing on:

```
#!/bin/sh
/bin/touch /tmp/svn-hook-worked
```

Comment: No error message nowhere in the system? Have you tried command line?

Comment: yeah, no errors at all, tried shell for hook, error logs for apache, not errors at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so the problem have been related to something different but somehow connected.

I have set /dev/null in syslog-nd for mail, and as it turnes out its changing ownership of /dev/null to root so svn and other stuff can't use it which was causing those problems above.

cheers,
/Marcin